# silverlight - reusing components

Tags: silverlight, templates, components, styles, reusability

I am trying to create some reusable components in **Silverlight2**. The difficulty comes when my components are using templates/styles that are shared with other components.

- From what I know, in silverlight you can add the style/template in the component itself (not good enough due to duplicate styles) or in the main app file (this does not help with reusing components in other silverlight projects).
- I've just read about templates added in silverlight toolkit (march release) but ... the template does not allow me to define named styles (for example I have more than one style for buttons)

My question: is it possible to create reusable components with styles/templates defined in a single place? (By reusable I mean to be reused in other projects)

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature coming in Silverlight 3 - due later this year (2009).
"Enhanced control skinning. Silverlight 3 provides easier skinning capabilities by keeping a common set of controls external from an application. This allows the sharing of styles and control skins between different applications. " [Silverlight.net](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx)